# Do these permutations commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I read in my textbook that disjoint cycles commute.
But what about $(1,2,3) = (1,3)(1,2)$ is it equal to $(1,2)(1,3) = (1,3,2)$ although they are not disjoint? And, if they are not equal how come in my textbook it says that $\langle(1,2,3)\rangle = \{(1),(1,2,3),(1,3,2) \}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific permutations are not equal. As the image of 1 is different, namely 2 and 3, respectively.

More generally, if you have two cycles that both start with 1, then they only give the same permutation if the string of numbers describing them is the same.

---

The notation $\langle (1,2,3) \rangle$ means the subgroup generated by the permutation $(1,2,3)$. It is true that $(1,3,2)$ is an element of this. Indeed, $(1,3,2)$ and $(1,2,3)$ generate the same subgroup. Howvever, this does not  mean the two elements are equal.

Comment: but how come they generate the same group ?

Comment: If you calculate $(1,2,3)(1,2,3)$ you will find it is $(1,3,2)$. And $(1,2,3)(1,2,3)(1,2,3)=(1)$. In the same way, $(1,3,2)(1,3,2)=(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)(1,3,2)(1,3,2)=(1)$. So they generate the same group. Or differently, $(1,2,3)(1,3,2)= (1)$. So the two permuations are inverses of each other and inverses generate the same subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

No, $\;(1\;2\;3)\neq (1\;3\;2)\;$ . In fact, the former one maps $\;1\;$ into $\;2\;$, whereas the latter maps it to $\;3\;$ .

Comment: but in my textbook , it says that $<(1,2,3)> = \{(1),(1,2,3),(1,3,2) \}$ how is this possible then ?

Comment: @Alkabary what is written is the subgroup generated by the permutation. (1,3,2) is an element of the subgroup generated by (1,2,3). Indeed, (1,3,2) and (1,2,3) generate the same subgroup. Howvever, this does not  mean the are equal.

Comment: but how come they generate the same subgroup ?

Comment: @Alkabary : $\;(1\;3\;2)=(1\;2\;3)^{-1}\;$ , and since an element and its inverse always generate the same cyclic group...